# Invalid Object name Exception

Tags: asp.net

I have created a table named Customerdetails which contains all the information regarding customers such as customer_id,name contact,etc.. I have created one form in which once i enter the customer name all other details should get displayed automatically..

Bt when i enter name in the name textbox ,i get exception as

> invalid object name Customerdetails.

I am developing this project in asp.net c#. Given below is my code sample..Your help will hugely appreciated.. thank you...!!

```
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Customerdetails where name='"+textBox2.Text+"'",con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = dr["customer_id"].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = dr["contact"].ToString();
                richTextBox1.Text = dr["address"].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = dr["veichle"].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = dr["veichle_no"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is unable to recognize your request for the `"Customerdetails"` table in your database.

Check to make sure that `Customerdetails` table exists, you have the appropriate permissions, and you may need to specify the owner of the table.